# MYSQL: AND statement causing expected results to not display

Tags: mysql

When I run the below query, I expect to get one result.

However, I get no results.

```
SELECT listings.*

FROM   `listings` 
       LEFT JOIN users 
              ON listings.user_id = users.user_id 
       LEFT JOIN listing_attributes 
              ON listings.listing_id = listing_attributes.listing_id

WHERE users.account_status = 1

AND ( listing_attributes.name LIKE 'collection_city' AND listing_attributes.content LIKE '%d%' ) 
AND ( listing_attributes.name LIKE 'collection_post_code' AND listing_attributes.content LIKE '%e%' ) 

GROUP BY listings.listing_id
```

I have identified the problem as these two lines

```
AND ( listing_attributes.name LIKE 'collection_city' AND listing_attributes.content LIKE '%d%' ) 
AND ( listing_attributes.name LIKE 'collection_post_code' AND listing_attributes.content LIKE '%e%' )
```

If I remove either of the lines, I get the result I expect.

I am thinking something is wrong with the way I am encompassing the results in the ().

In essence I am wishing to check that multiple values exist in listing_attributes for a result to be as needed.

Comment: So, you want listings which have **both** attributes matching?

Comment: Or do you want listings with **either** attribute matching?

Comment: I want both attributes to match.

Comment: There are three different ways of achieving the result you want in the linked duplicates: `JOIN`, `EXISTS` clauses, and `GROUP BY` with `HAVING`.

Answer (score 2):

I think that your logic is not correct. You must use the operator `OR` for this condition. Otherwise the condition will be `false`.

```
{

  (  listing_attributes.name LIKE 'collection_city' AND listing_attributes.content LIKE '%d%' ) 
    OR ( listing_attributes.name LIKE 'collection_post_code' AND listing_attributes.content LIKE '%e%' )


}
```

Comment: This is not correct. This will return rows which have either attribute, not rows which have both attributes.

Comment: By rows I mean listings.

Answer (score 0):

Given that `listings.listing_id` is a key of `listings` you can use a `HAVING` clause checking for the sums of the logical expressions are greater then `0`. This works because logical expressions in numeric context evaluate to `0` or `1` in MySQL.

Your join with `user` silently becomes an inner join because of the `WHERE` as `NULL`s cannot equal `1`. Since the `NULL`s from the left join of `listing_attributes` cannot make the `HAVING` clause true you can also convert that join to an inner join.

```
SELECT listings.*
       FROM listings
            INNER JOIN users
                       ON listings.user_id = users.user_id
            INNER JOIN listing_attributes
                       ON listings.listing_id = listing_attributes.listing_id
       WHERE users.account_status = 1
       GROUP BY listings.listing_id
       HAVING sum(listing_attributes.name LIKE 'collection_city'
                  AND listing_attributes.content LIKE '%d%') > 0
              AND sum(listing_attributes.name LIKE 'collection_post_code'
                      AND listing_attributes.content LIKE '%e%') > 0;
```

Comment: This is not correct. This will return rows which have either attribute, not rows which have both attributes.

Answer (score 0):

Please use below query, Try moving the condition to `on` clause

```
SELECT listings.*
FROM `listings` 
       LEFT JOIN users 
              ON listings.user_id = users.user_id AND users.account_status = 1
       LEFT JOIN listing_attributes 
              ON listings.listing_id = listing_attributes.listing_id AND ( listing_attributes.name LIKE 'collection_city' AND listing_attributes.content LIKE '%d%' ) AND ( listing_attributes.name LIKE 'collection_post_code' AND listing_attributes.content LIKE '%e%' )
GROUP BY listings.listing_id;
```